# Java memory management while returning the new object

Tags: java, memory-management

I want to know better way for coding in terms of memory management,

Method 1:

```
Obj temp;
public static Obj fun1() {
      ......
      ......
      Obj temp = new Obj();
      return temp;
}
```

Method2:

```
public static Obj fun1() {
     ........
     .........
     return new Obj;
}
```

which method will be good ? both method does the same work. but second method returns creating new `Object`, whereas first method create `Object` store it in variable and returns the variable.

Please consider that my function is going to have large number of such function returning `Object` of different class. and they will be called many many times during execution of Automated Test programme. So which one should I use and why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a singleton pattern . Create static object once if same instance can be used across
It will be like

```
static Object temp;
public Object getObjectInstance(){
if(temp==null){
temp = new Object();
}

return temp; 
}
```

Comment: OP  clearly specifies, that he/she wants to * large number of such function returning objects of different class*. I do not think that a singleton pattern is, what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are ok, and have the same impact on the memory. The first one is used if you want to do something with the object inside the function before return it. The secone one assumes you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer:**  There is very insignificant difference in 2 approaches you specified. As you are also aware that in both approaches a new object will be created, so that works well for you. Now your concern that in second approach a new variable will be used for store the object reference - but it is really insignificant because as soon as method will end, all the local variables created by the method will be removed from stack.

**Concept:**

- Objects live in heap of area of the memory.
- Variables live in the stack, and as soon as method finishes all local variables created by that method are removed from stack.

**In nutshell:** For your given you methods, hardly any difference in terms of memory management.

Comment: Have you got your answer, if not then please write your answer so that other's can be benefited from it. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

There is an actual difference within bytecode. Let's take the following class.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final int LIMIT = 10_000_000;
        final int RUNS = 10;
        for (int run = 0; run < RUNS; ++run) {
            Test[] t = new Test[LIMIT];
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
                t[i] = fun1();
            }

            System.out.println(  "fun1: "
                               + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000_000d)
                               + "s");

            t = new Test[LIMIT];
            start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
                t[i] = fun2();
            }

            System.out.println(  "fun2: "
                               + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000_000d)
                               + "s");

        }
    }

    public static Test fun1() {
        return (new Test());
    }

    public static Test fun2() {
        Test t = new Test();
        return (t);
    }
}
```

When you look at the bytecode for the methods `fun1()` and `fun2()`, they will look like this:

```
public static Test fun1();
  Code:
    0: new           #1                  // class Test
    3: dup
    4: invokespecial #20                 // Method "<init>":()V
    7: areturn

public static Test fun2();
  Code:
    0: new           #1                  // class Test
    3: dup
    4: invokespecial #20                 // Method "<init>":()V
    7: astore_0 // those lines are
    8: aload_0  // unique to fun2()
    9: areturn
```

As you execute this code, you may notice that the execution times get faster and faster. I think this is due to the JIT-compiler. At the end, however, there is hardly a difference performancewise.

Comment: OP wanted to understand from the memory management perspective .. Yes, there would be difference in byte code because object assignment is happening, but it really has very insignificant effect ..

Comment: My point is: the JIT-compiler seems to optimize this code. The optimization will most likely have an effect on the memory (e.g. the JIT-compiler "notices", that the `astore_0` and `aload_0` are unnecessary). Therefore, this is a question, which is not trivial to answer (if it is even possible to answer).

Comment: I am really not sure if there is any sort of optimization in this particular case, it is simply that compiler has generated the assembly code instruction which corresponds to its respective the Java statement .. But underlying thing we both know is that 2 approaches of OP has really insignificant impact in terms memory and performance ..

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are almost similar. In method 1, if you are returning immediately after assigning the object to reference variable, then there is no point in assigning it to refence variable. In which case method 2 should be opted for.

```
Obj temp = new Obj(); //if you are not doing anything with temp but just returning then go with method 2
  return temp;
```

However if you have to mutate the object ot do some operations, then method1 should be good as you will be getting the reference to that object in 'temp'

```
Obj temp = new Obj(); //if temp is used before return, then go with method 1
  return temp;
```

Note: Only the object takes the memory on heap NOT the reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well I discussed with expert, have found that using following method will create a memory allocation in stack every time we create new object.

```
method1 () {
return new ClassObj();
}
method2 () {
return new ClassObj();
}
method3 () {
return new ClassObj();
}
method4 () {
return new ClassObj();
}
method5 () {
return new ClassObj();
}
```

and this stack memory go on allocating. If we are calling this function many times during run ( as it happens generally in running automated script) same function called many times again and again, this stack accumulation go on increasing.

So to avoid this use some temp object that will catch the object returned by method. So instead of allocation memory in stack, this will delete previous memory data of temp object and replace it with new one.

```
ClassObj temp;
method1 () {
temp = new ClassObj();
return temp;
}
method2 () {
temp = new ClassObj();
return temp;
}
method3 () {
temp = new ClassObj();
return temp;
}
method4 () {
temp = new ClassObj();
return temp;
}
method5 () {
temp = new ClassObj();
return temp;
}
```